# How to increase width of the sidebar menu in bookdown

Tags: html, css, r, r-markdown, bookdown

I'd like to increase the width of the sidebar menu in my bookdown.
I need more space for my chapter headings...
[Here's a basic example](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown-demo/)

I tried :

```
.book-summary {
  width: 650px;
}
```

But it's certainly more complicated...  especially to make it work with the toggle button.
Maybe a css trick ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: which output format are you using when you render the Rmd files?

Comment: I'm using bookdown::gitbook output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a common ground, we can take an [github example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/tree/master/inst/examples) of "bookdown: Authoring Books and Technical Documents with R Markdown" and add `css` below to it `style.css` ([here](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/blob/master/inst/examples/css/style.css)):

```
.book.with-summary .book-header.fixed {
    left: 650px;
}

.book.with-summary .book-body {
    left: 650px;
}

.book .book-summary {
    width: 650px;
}
```

Does this helps?